Convergence of a series & meromorphic function
I have some questions on the following exercise both on the practical and theoretical part...

Determinate the domain of convergence for
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-2}(z-3)^n$$
and show that the sum $f(z)$ could be extended to a meromorphic function $F$.


My approach is the following, let $w = z-3,k = -n$ then
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-2}(z-3)^n = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{w}\bigg)^k$$
So we need
$$\bigg|\frac{1}{w}\bigg| < 1 \iff |z-3| >1$$
which is the regione outside the radius one circle centered in $(3,0)$. In this region I can evaluate the sum and
$$\begin{align*}f(z) &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-2}(z-3)^n= -1 - \frac{1}{z-3} +\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z-3}}\\
&= -1 - \frac{1}{z-3} +\frac{z-3}{z-4} \\
& = \frac{25}{(z-4)(z-3)}
\end{align*}$$
this last one is defined on $\Bbb C - \{3,4\}$ hence meromorphic. I guess that the function $F$ is this one.
My question is (hoping my calculations are correct) whenever I have a geometric sum type series I can do this extension out of the convergence disk without any problems?

I'm adding this last part: if I need to evaluate $F(z)$'s Laurent series in $z=3$
$$\begin{align*}F(z) &= -1 - \frac{1}{z-3} +\frac{z-3}{z-4} = -1 - \frac{1}{z-3} -\frac{z-3}{1 -(z-3)} \\
&=-1 - \frac{1}{z-3} -(z-3)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(z-3)^n\\
&=-1 - \frac{1}{z-3} -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(z-3)^{n+1} \\
&=- \frac{1}{z-3} - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(z-3)^{k}
\end{align*}$$
is this a valid approach?

Thank you for the help!

For the first question, what you have done looks good. The main idea, as you have done, is to first rewrite the series in the form of a geometric series where it is straightforward to determine convergence conditions. Then you next use the series expansion on the set $\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z - 3| > 1 \}$ in order to obtain an expression of $f(z)$ on $\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z - 3| > 1 \}$ which can easily be extended to a meromorphic function on as large of an open subset of the complex plane as possible.
For the second question, what you have done is a valid way to evaluate the Laurent series of $f$ at $3$. When calculating Laurent series in general, it is a good practice to rewrite the function in a way which allows you to make use of geometric series in order to obtain the desired Laurent series expansion at the given point. You are making certain assumptions while obtaining this Laurent expansion though, so it may be good to spell out what those assumptions are, namely that it is valid for $z\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $0 < |z-3| < 1$.
